Contribution Page Custom Field Upload Image
In the Manage Contribution Pages interface, which is quite simple, I want to customize a section where I can upload an image. This image would then be used as the background for the Contribution Pages. I know that the extension available at https://github.com/JMAConsulting/biz.jmaconsulting.contributionpagecustomfield offers similar functionality, but it does not support image uploads and cannot achieve the effect I desire. Is there another way to accomplish what I'm looking for?

maybe worth asking on that extension Issues page if they would consider adding that feature?

Should be an easy fix to support this.
